# Let the height of the UIButton's image be the same height as the UIButton's text label

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I want to make a UIButton which has a image on the left side of it. This is how it looks like now:

[image]

This are the settings:

[image]

The image's height is far to large. Is it possible to resize it in StoryBoard to have the same height as the UIButton? The aspect ratio should be 1:1 of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here, is that the `imageView` within the button is not 'directly' accessible through Interface Builder. You can however use the **User Defined Runtime Attributes** (in the Identity inspector) to set the content mode of the inner `imageView`. Feels a little hacky, but gets the job done.

[image: <code>imageView.contentMode</code> - <code>Number</code> - <code>1</code>]

The value `1` corresponds to the raw value of the enum [UIViewContentMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontentmode):

```
scaleToFill == 0
scaleAspectFit == 1
scaleAspectFill == 2
etc.
```

The image on the button wil not render "correctly" at Design Time, but it will at runtime.